# font awesome icon with laravel 5 form

Tags: html, css, laravel, font-awesome, laravel-form

I have a form in `laravel5` like this

```
{!! Form::text('name', '' , array('placeholder' => 'Name' , 'class' => 'form-control') ) !!}
```

I need to use a icon inside this textBox,I'm using `FontAwesome 4.7.0`,in the documentation it says the to put the FontAwesome class inside the `<i>` tag but I have no idea how to insert the `<i>` inside the laravel Form. 
I have tried this

```
<i class="fa fa-user-circle-o">
{!! Form::text('name', '' , array('placeholder' => 'Name' , 'class' => 'form-control') ) !!}</i>
```

How should I embed the tag?

Comment: Can you point us to the docs you are looking at?  All the documentation I'm seeing there, they also have it all wrapped in a `form-group` div and the `i` element is wrapped in a `span` element with class `input-group-addon`.  It should be no different for Laravel except the input is going to be generated by your form helper.

Comment: http://fontawesome.io/icon/user-circle-o/   this!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looking at the bootstrap 3 examples on this page http://fontawesome.io/examples/, I believe you need to do something like the following?

```
<div class="input-group margin-bottom-sm">
    <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-user-circle-o"></i></span>
    {!! Form::text('name', '' , array('placeholder' => 'Name' , 'class' => 'form-control') ) !!}
</div>
```

Comment: the icon is larger than the text box,why is that so?

Comment: remove `fa-fw` it will become smaller.

Comment: Thanks, I removed that portion from the answer.